# Non-resizeable QDialog with fixed size in Qt?

Tags: qt, qdialog

I have a Qt dialog application. Now I dont want that dialog to be resizeable. I am not sure how to achieve this. I tried a bunch of things but still when the dialog launches this dialog can be resized.

What is the property that i should set to disable the dialog/Widget resize.

I also tried

```
setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed);
```

But i get an error saying..

```
source\nimcac_settingsMain.cpp(36) : error C2248:
**'QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy' : cannot access private member declared in class 'QSizePolicy'**
        p:\ThirdPartyExports\Qt\export\4.3\4.3.1f14\include\QtGui\../../src\gui\
kernel\qsizepolicy.h(177) : see declaration of 'QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy'
        p:\ThirdPartyExports\Qt\export\4.3\4.3.1f14\include\QtGui\../../src\gui\
kernel\qsizepolicy.h(34) : see declaration of 'QSizePolicy'
```

Kindly help me out with this.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I don't know if you already tried it, but `QWidget::setFixedSize` should do what you want

Comment: It seems to me that although this avoids resizing, you must know beforehand the window dimensions (and this don't always obey font changes, screen scaling and so on).

Answer (score 121):

The compile error you get is because you try to pass a `QSizePolicy::Policy` to `setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy)`, but there's no implicit conversion from `QSizePolicy::Policy` (which is the policy for one dimension) to `QSizePolicy` (which is a class containing, among other things, one `Policy` per dimension (height, width)). `QSizePolicy` doesn't work on top-level widgets (windows) anyway, though.

`setFixedSize()` only works if you know the size of the dialog in advance (and usually you don't, what with changing font sizes and languages). You can do

```
window()->setFixedSize( window()->sizeHint() );
```

but it's much better to use

```
window->layout()->setSizeConstraint( QLayout::SetFixedSize );
```

That lets the layout determine the size of the dialog, but doesn't allow resizing, which I assume is what you were asking for.

Comment: `window->layout()->setSizeConstraint( QLayout::SetFixedSize );` is almost what I need because it updates with changing font etc. But I would like to fix only the height but not the width. Is this possible?

Comment: You're the MVP. This makes my QDialog not user-resizable, but it still resizes whenever its content changes size.

Answer (score 27):

```
this->setFixedSize(this->width(),this->height());
```

Comment: Or simply `this->setFixedSize(this->size());`

Comment: Or even simpler :) `setFixedSize(size());`

Answer (score 9):

You need to change the windowFlags of the dialog and set it to Qt::MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint.

**This only works in windows**.

For more information please see this example:
http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.5/widgets-windowflags.html

Answer (score 8):

On QT Creator, in the UI editor, click on the top object in the properties window, then scroll at the bottom in the Layout part. You should see the layoutSizeConstraint property.

Set the `layoutSizeConstraint` to `SetFixedSize`.

Answer (score 4):

If you use QtCreator (of course you are) you can set the property HorizontalsizePolicy to fixed and Vertical Policy also to Fixed. Then you can set the maximumSize to the dimensions you want. The window will not maximise again.

Answer (score 2):

In code you can do something like this,

```
Dialog->resize(581, 292);
QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(WaterLevelEditorDialog->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
Dialog->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
Dialog->setMinimumSize(QSize(581, 292));
Dialog->setMaximumSize(QSize(581, 292));
Dialog->setSizeGripEnabled(false);
```

In QtCreator do as follows,

1. Select the dialog box widget
2. Locate the dialog box widget in Object Window
3. In Object Window, right click on dialog box object to popup a menu
4. Select "Size Constraints" -> "Set Maximum Size" from the menu
5. Right click again on dialog object to popup a menu
6. Select "Size Constraints" -> "Set Minimum Size"
7. In Property Window,

   - ensure "sizePolicy"->"Horizontal Policy" has value "Fixed"
   - ensure "sizePolicy"->"Vertical Policy" has value "Fixed"
   - ensure "sizeGripEnabled" is not checked

Answer (score 1):

From the Qt documentation, `setSizePolicy()` method either takes zero argument or two arguments but cannot be one argument. That's why you get this compilation error. From my experiment, if you don't set the fixed size. This method has no use. The window can still be resizable.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to set the maxium size to 0.

```c
this->setMaxiumSize(QSize(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are designing UI in QML and launching using QDeclarativeView, try the below code.

```
QScopedPointer<QmlApplicationViewer> viewer(QmlApplicationViewer::create());
.
.
.
//To make the window non-resizable
viewer->setFixedSize(viewer->width(),viewer->height());
```

Here QmlApplicationViewer is derived from QDeclarativeView.